# Can't find androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, android-manifest, build-settings

I am working on a Visual Studio Cordova project which works on Windows, iOS and Android, and looking for `AndroidManifest.xml` or a build settings file and couldn't find any. I tried building it with no errors, but still couldn't find the file. Any suggestions, where/what I should be looking for?

Comment: Thanks Sky Kelsey & Melvin

Comment: Any suggestions on what kind of script should I use for updating android:versionCode and android:versionName in AndroidManifest.xml ? I was thinking of ant, but not sure if its a good choice for a Visual Studio Cordova project. I have heard of cordova plugins for build scripts, but not sure how they work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in your project root inside `platforms/android`.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova generates a AndroidManifest.xml in `platforms/android`, but it's going to be reseted with each rebuild. If you need to add some data to it, you will have to create your own AndroidManifest.xml in `res/native/android` that will be automatically merged to the one in `platforms/android`.

You can read (a bit) more in the official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn757053.aspx